Why can't I give a default value to params.fasta in main.nf of my new pipeline (Nextflow/nf-core)
When I try to change the value of the fasta parameter by putting params.fasta = getGenomeAttribute('fasta') in the main script of my pipeline, if I try to print the value or $params.fasta or if I try to pass it to a module, I get an error saying that the module doesn't take null as an input or it simply prints out null.
I just used the nf-core create method to make a new pipeline and used the normal template.

It's not enough details. "My pipeline" needs more explanation. Is this nf-core template?

@ATpoint yes its the template

@ATpoint nf-core template* do u have any idea why?

No, nf-core template is a big blackbox to me. I tried some time ago to understand it and failed. I suggest you ask this at their slack channel.

Please add code so that we can see how you are invoking/retrieving parameter value. in any case I think it would need to be "${params.fasta}" with the curly bracket
